# how to create mysql table in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have following nodejs code that will initialize the mysql connection and after that I can use sql queries.

I have good experience with MongoDB schema, and new to Mysql.
I want to know how do I maintain my tables schema/structure in Nodejs code so that if I update any column or column properties that will reflects in mysql database.

Here is my code:

```
const mysqlx = require("@mysql/xdevapi");
const config = require("config");
const mysqlClient = async()=>{
const session = await mysqlx.getSession(config.MYSQL.CONNECTION_STRING);
 await session
      .sql(
        `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${config.MYSQL.DATABASE} CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
      )
      .execute();
    await session.sql(`USE ${config.MYSQL.DATABASE}`).execute();
    await session.sql(`CREATE TABLE Persons ( PersonID int,LastName varchar(255),FirstName varchar(255),Address varchar(255),City varchar(255));`).execute();}
```

If I run this code, it will successfully connects to my Mysql database and will create the table inside database.

The problem I am facing is If I re-run my code than I will get error that table name is already exists.
If I use "IF NOT EXISTS" clause in sql query then its ok. But then how I will update the column defination.
And in same If I need to add one more column or delete one column than how I will achieve in my nodejs code.

With Mongoose I am clear just updating the collection schema as per need works. But in mysql it seems very complex for me.

Anyone can help in coding the solution that whenver my nodejs server will run it will create table, add/delete column specified later on etc...

Answer (score 2):

i think you mentioned about [table migrations](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=table%20migrations)

some of the different betweens `MySQL` and `MongoDB` are

- MySQL is a table-based system, where MongoDB is a document-based non-relational database management system
- MySQL stores data using tables and rows, enforces referential integrity, and uses structured query language (SQL) for data access. Each database table `consists` of rows and columns, where MongoDB does not need a table schema, because it stores data in documents. That's why it doesn't need to be declared before allowing data input.

How to create table whenever server will run?

we can use [mysql table migrations](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) to handle it.

Noted: *in my opinion, this is not a good way to do in `production` environment, keep in mind that use it when you are working in `development` environment*

usually, you have to create `script migration` manually. but there a lot of awesome libraries that can handle it.

tools:

- [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize)
- [Typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)
- [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)